# Whats the best CMS/Website Starter kit for my project?

Tags: .net, asp.net, web-applications, web

I need to build a company profile website, which will contain a gallery of images which this company designed before, and will contain the normal stuff, such as about us, contact us, menus for fast navigation, and also need to give this company a way to edit the site them selves, so which CMS/Website template you recommend for me?
-Free will be better

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since this question is tagged `.NET`, take a look at [N2](http://n2cms.com/) -

> **N2 Open Source ASP.NET CMS**
>
> N2 is a lightweight CMS framework to help you build great web sites that anyone can update.

Answer (score 1):

Try [OpenSourceCMS.com](http://www.opensourcecms.com/). It lets you demo a lot of the CMS's out there, so you can try a few out and then pick the one that best suits your needs. They have examples of both open source and commercial CMS's, blogs, forums, and wikis and they have them for both .NET and PHP.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at Blogengine.net (http://www.dotnetblogengine.net/ ). It doubles up as a CMS and a blogging engine.
Community Server (http://communityserver.com/) is available as a solution for all your needs, but the licensing terms may not suit you.
Das Blog(http://www.dasblog.info/) is another one.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend [DotNetNuke](http://www.dotnetnuke.com). There is a very large active community. [Here](http://www.loadedtech.com.au/web_solutions/web_design_development/dotnetnuke.aspx) is a site with some nice demos of the editing functionality. I recommend going with DotNetNuke Community Edition 4.9.2. It is free and very stable. (Professional is the same thing with direct support.) It provides all the basic functionality you need and there are many free and pay [third](http://marketplace.dotnetnuke.com/) [party](http://www.snowcovered.com/snowcovered2/) modules and skins available.

Answer (score 0):

Check http://graffiticms.codeplex.com/

> Description:
>
> Creating and maintaining a site has never been easier. Graffiti CMS
>   allows you to quickly publish and maintain dynamic content Web sites
>   with little or no knowledge of Web programming. Announcements
>
> The first open source stable release will be Graffiti CMS 1.3. A
>   branch for this has been created in the source code repository. One of
>   the goals with 1.3 is to make zero database changes so it will be
>   super simple to upgrade from older versions. This branch needs testing
>   and some simplification done around the new url routing features. List
>   of features coming soon... Do not use 2.0 branch for your production
>   web site going forward, use the 1.3 branch for now.

Answer (score -2):

I Would suggest [DotNetNuke](http://www.dotnetnuke.com/). It is the most best open source. It is free 4.92 for the current community version. It is easy to manage for database for the backend.